# Unable to display an Icon on a Menu added at run time to a Virtual Image List

Tags: delphi

I cannot get an icon to appear on a menu item added at run time.
I am adding a menu item to the main menu whose images property are linked to a TVirtualImageList which is linked to a TImageCollection.  All the fixed images are held in the Virtual Image list and at run time I add additional menu items adding each image as an Icon to the Virtual Image List. The main menu has a dummy menu item to which the additional menus are attached.

```
function LoadIconFromFile(FileName: String; Var Icon: TIcon): Integer;  overload;
var SHInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
  Result := -1;
  if not FileExists(FileName) then exit;
  SHGetFileInfo(PChar(FileName), 0, SHInfo, SizeOf(SHInfo), SHGFI_ICON OR SHIL_LARGE);
  Icon.Handle := SHInfo.hIcon;
  Icon.Transparent := true;
  result := $1000;
end;    

TmpIcon := TIcon.Create;
LoadIconFromFile(FileName, TmpIcon);
MenuItem.ImageIndex := vilMenues.AddIcon(TmpIcon);
image1.Picture.Graphic := TmpIcon;
TmpIcon.Free;
MainMenu.BaseMenuItem.Add(MenuItem);
```

Just to ensure I was actually picking up the icon correctly I also display in a TImage. The additional menu item gets added and the Icon appears in the TImage control but never appears on the menu. I know the image gets added to the image list because the Image Count increases. I have tried detaching the image list from the mainmenu before updating and reattaching after but that has made no difference.  I am beginning to wonder whether TVirtualImageList is capable of handling mixed sources of images?

Can anyone advise me what I might do to solve this issue?

Comment: On a side note, you should get rid of the `FileExists()` check and instead check the return value of `SHGetFileInfo()` for success/failure

Comment: Have you tried adding the icon to the linked `TImageCollection` rather than to the `TVirtualImageList` directly? The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Supporting_high-DPI_images_with_the_Image_Collection_and_Virtual_ImageList_components) does say: "*Note: To add, insert, and/or replace bitmaps in TVirtualImageList **you must use methods to add, insert, and/or replace items from the ImageCollection**.*", so I assume that applies to icons, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TImageCollection` doesn't support icons.

When you use the `AddIcon` method, `TCustomImageList.AddIcon` calls the overridden method `TVirtualImageList.DoChange` which updates the entire virtual image list from the image collection.

So if you have 3 images in the virtual image list and call `AddIcon`, it'll return a new image index of 3 and there are now 4 images in the list. But then the virtual image list is recreated and its `Count` is back to 3.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my  suspicions.  I have previously tried adding to the Image collection without success but I will give it another go as it makes much more sense.  I suspect I will need to convert my Icon to a png for it to be accepted by the Image Collection.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with the following code:

```
TmpIcon := TIcon.Create;
Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
LoadIconFromFile(FileName, TmpIcon);// get icon from file
tmpIcon.SaveToStream(Strm);
s := 'X'+IntToStr(idx);  // Add a name for new item
ImageCollection1.Add(s, strm);  // Add to collection
idy:= ImageCollection1.Count -1;  // Get the index for it
vilMenues.Add(s,idy);  // Add it to virtual image list
MenuItem.ImageIndex := vilMenues.Count -1;
Strm.Free;
TmpIcon.Free;
```

Rather clumsy I feel there must be a better way...

Comment: Apparently ImageCollection1.Add is supported by Delphi Sydney and above.